# Mathematical toys?

Tags: reference-request, big-list, popular-math

Anybody know of "serious" mathematical ornaments or toys like the [Gömböc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6mb%C3%B6c),
etc?

Already have a rubix and abacus (that's more of a tool though).

Comment: Define "serious."

Comment: I was being lack there, perhaps I should define what I do want by what I don't want; placing the correct shape in the hole, children games and so on.

Comment: You probably mean "lax" in the above comment (somewhat Ironic since in your question statement it probably should be "Rubik's" cube).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On [Shapeways](http://www.shapeways.com/), you can find a variety of mathematical ornaments.

My favorites are the differential geometric surfaces designed by [Bachman](http://www.shapeways.com/shops/bachman).  I also like [Bathsheba's](http://www.shapeways.com/shops/bathsheba) designs as well.

[image]

(Sorry the image is so large.  Is there a way to reduce the size?)

Answer (score 15):

For when the Möbius strip is too pedestrian, the good people at Acme Co. claim their [Klein bottles](http://www.kleinbottle.com/) are the "finest closed, non-orientable, boundary-free manifolds sold anywhere in our three spatial dimensions."

Comment: His book the Cuckoo's Egg is a lot of fun, too.

Answer (score 10):

I have a [Rattleback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rattleback) at my desk.  Fun to fiddle with while thinking.

Answer (score 9):

The Rubik cube. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Oh yeah obviously I have one of those - I have some with more than 6 faces also, though in the end it's a tougher algorithm. Very nice puzzles though.

Answer (score 7):

Spirograph from Hasbro. You can make lots of famous mathematical curves with its pieces: epicycloids, hypocycloids, etc. MathWorld has an [article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Spirograph.html) on some of these curves.

Comment: I love the Spirograph; +1 of course.

Answer (score 6):

[Zometool](http://zometool.com) is a construction kit which has 2-, 3-, and 5-fold symmetry, which is great for building (3D projections of) [the 120-cell](http://www.zometool.com/Hyperdo), or just for playing around.

Comment: @Adam:  Seeing this, I thought of K'nex.  Their website doesn't have any info on what symmetries are supported on the home page.  I grew up with tinker toys.

Answer (score 6):

Wikipedia has a section on [mechanical puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_puzzle).

As for myself, my fascination with algebraic topology began with metal link puzzles or [hanayama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanayama).

Of course, [Tower of Hanoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) is a classic.

Of interest may be the reference: [Adventures in Group Theory: Rubik’s Cube, Merlin’s Machine, and Other Mathematical Toys](http://www.maths.dur.ac.uk/~dma0jf/JoynerRubikbook.pdf) by David Joyner. Book description in [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0801869471).

Answer (score 4):

While it may be a 'children's toy', the [Switch Pitch](http://hoberman.com/fold/Switchpitch/switchpitch.htm) works remarkably well as an object of mathematical sculpture; it's fundamentally based on the fact that the vertices of a regular cube are also the vertices of two (interlocked) regular tetrahedra (if your cube is $\{0,1\}^3$, take the vertices with $i+j+k$ respectively odd or even).  It helps that people can't help but fiddle with it; it's been a perfect hand-fidgetting toy for me.

Answer (score 4):

The [Oloid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oloid) is fun to touch, to [watch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GM3_JuFgJ2E) and [understand](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oloid).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a [Tippe Top](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tippe_top).

Answer (score 2):

Love zometool [1]

[1]: http://www.zometool.com/  for geometry, platonic and archimedean solids, among others/

Answer (score 2):

[Double pendulum.](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=double%20pendulum&oq=double%20pend&aq=0&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=148l3925l0l5024l11l11l0l1l1l1l339l1994l2-4.3l7l0)

Answer (score 2):

[http://tavernpuzzles.stores.yahoo.net/puzzle.html http://ep.yimg.com/ca/I/tavernpuzzles_2188_4561747](http://ep.yimg.com/ca/I/tavernpuzzles_2188_4561747)

Goal: Remove the big ring

http://tavernpuzzles.stores.yahoo.net/puzzle.html

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 2 different toy devices that mimic a Gray code.
One can be seen at http://mypuzzlecollection.blogspot.com/2011/12/brain.html.
The other is named "Spin Out".

Comment: Also the Towers of Hanoi.

Answer (score 1):

Check Montessori mathematical materials like the binomial cube just google it

Answer (score 0):

Sudoku and all other logic trainers would also fit.

Answer (score 0):

Origami to fold shapes to find surface area of 3 dimensional shapes.  Wooden blocks.  The Game of 24.  Math Jeopardy.  Bucky balls.  Sudoku.  Computer games with rotations and other types of transformations.

Answer (score 0):

In a blatant reference to my own creative work, I submit for your consideration the mathematical artwork presented on my Shapeways Shop at this address: https://www.shapeways.com/shops/Feingold_Math_Art
But there are a huge number of other artists whose work can also be found in other shops there.